# Accessing individual objects created by "new", through pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers

I am dynamically creating 3 objects of MyClass.

```
MyClass *ptr = new MyClass[3];
```

I'm assuming ptr is the address of the first instance of said object. I can do

```
(*ptr).doStuff();
```

However, when I try to access the 2nd object, via

```
(* (ptr + sizeof(MyClass)) ).doStuff();
```

It throws an exception. How am I supposed to get at the other objects?

Comment: ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the options (from most recommended to least recommended):

```
ptr[1].doStuff();
(ptr+1)->doStuff();
(*(ptr+1)).doStuff();
((MyClass*)((char*)ptr+sizeof(MyClass)))->doStuff();
(*(MyClass*)((char*)ptr+sizeof(MyClass))).doStuff();
```

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Where else do you think I should go?

Comment: Further into the dark recesses of the language, of course!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: LOL, good one. But I don't see a lot more I can add at this point, besides changing `char*` to `int` and that kinda stuff (which is not very safe, by the way)...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Why did you edit the post by the way?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Oh... well I didn't reject it or anything, just didn't see any change made... What other lines do you have in mind?

Comment: When I say I failed, I mean that I wrote them, realised they didn't work, and subsequently removed them again. And now I've run out of ideas.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Oh... so I guess that you should take back your disappointment then, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 2):

The valid code will look as

```
(* (ptr + 1) ).doStuff();
```

This is so-called the pointer arithmetic. You "shift" the pointer to the number of elements you want.

Answer (score 2):

That's because incrementing `ptr` by 1 does not simply increment the pointer by 1 byte. Instead, it moves the pointer so far as to point to the next element to the array. Instead of your final line you have to write

```
(* (ptr + 1) ).doStuff();
```

or:

```
(ptr+1)->doStuff();
```

or, even more readable, as the commenters have suggested:

```
ptr[1]->doStuff();
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic already takes the size of the pointee type into account. So you should plus  `1`, not `sizeof(MyClass)`.

Otherwise you are plussing too far.